# How to create new page in wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to create a new page in my plugin named as `custompage`

I dont want to add page in Main Menu list..

If it's possible???

Comment: `admin.php?page=newpage.php$name=student` is invalid URL

Comment: How to create a new page in a plugin? @bodi0

Comment: Basically you have to register and add several administration pages. So you have to call `add_menu_page()` function couple of times in your main plugin file, see the documentation http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page , also this http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus and this http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

Comment: That page shows in menu... I want hide that page frm menu list. if it's passible @bodi0

Comment: Yes, read this http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-remove-menu-item-in-wordpress-admin-panel/

Comment: Please, mark my comment as useful, so other users can benefit from this info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_newpage' );

function register_newpage(){
    add_menu_page('custom_page', 'custom', 'administrator','custom', 'custompage');
    remove_menu_page('custom');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following code in your plugin .

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_newpage' );

function register_newpage(){
    add_menu_page( 'newpage title', '', 'manage_options', 'myplugin/newpage.php', '', plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ), 6 );
}
```

keep newpage.php in your plugin folder.

Comment: I know that @Arkaprava.. I dont want to show page in menu list

Comment: it will not show in menu, i have kept menu_name blank.

Comment: otherwise create a newpage.php and include wp-load.php from root folder, then execute your code.