# How do I add a new page using code thru a Wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I followed the chosen answer here -> [How to create new page in wordpress plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656140/how-to-create-new-page-in-wordpress-plugin)

and I added the following code in a new Wordpress plugin folder and file and then activated in the Wordpress admin menu. Yet I don't have a new page created when I go to the slug demosite.com/custom/

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_newpage' );

function register_newpage(){
    add_menu_page('custom_page', 'custom', 'administrator','custom', 'custompage');
    remove_menu_page('custom');
}
```

Do I have to do something special to make my Wordpress plugin code work? I really need to be able to add a new page using my plugin functionality.

Comment: are you creating a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

For create fronted page when plugin activation used  [register_activation_hook()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) like below. 
`register_activation_hook()` function registers a plugin function to be run when the plugin is activated.

The first thing we do on activation is check that the current user is allowed to activate plugins. We do this using the current_user_can function

Finally, we create our new page, after we check that a page with the same name does not exist

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'register_newpage_plugin_activation' );
function register_newpage_plugin_activation() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) ) return;

    global $wpdb;

    if ( null === $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT post_name FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_name = 'new-page-slug'", 'ARRAY_A' ) ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    // create post object
    $page = array(
        'post_title'  => __( 'New Page' ),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => $current_user->ID,
        'post_type'   => 'page',
    );
    // insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $page );
    }
}
```

Here is a full list of parameters accepted by the [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) function

After plugin active successfully you can access your page using `demosite.com/new-page-slug/`

Comment: @Simon answer is helpful or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you intended for the page to be created only once if so you should do it during plugin activation.

You might want to consider the following pseudo-ish code:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'moveFile' );


function moveFile(){ 
    if( check if post exists ){
      wp_insert_post() # obviously title is "whatever", following convention
      #move the file to themes folder
      $source = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "page-whatever.php";
      $destination = get_template_directory() . "/page-whatever.php";
      $cmd = 'cp ' . $source . ' ' . $destination;
      exec($cmd);
    }
}
```

It's similar to the code answered by Ankur, but this sample let you have a custom page. Caveat, my method uses exec() command.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```html
/* If you want create a page with syn page template on plugin activation so see below example */

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate' );
function activate() { 
    $the_slug = 'our-services';
    $args = array(
    'name'        => $the_slug,
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'numberposts' => 1
    );
    $my_posts = get_posts($args);
    if(empty($my_posts)){
        $my_post = array(
            'post_title'    => 'Our Services',
            'post_content'  => '',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_author'   => 1,
            'post_type'     => 'page',
            'post_name'     => 'our-services'
            );
    
        // Insert the post into the database
        $post_id=wp_insert_post( $my_post );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_page_template', 'page-templates/our-services.php' );
    }
}


/* page-template - our-services.php* /

<?php
/*
* Template Name: our-services
*/ 

get_header();
get_footer();
?>
```